# Excel Power Query: How to add data from a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is:

I have Power Query pull a list of employees from a database and load to a spreadsheet.

From here, users need to add columns next to the employee names (becauase IT won't add this data tot he database, it needs to be done in excel).

So, for example, Column A = employee name (provided by power query) and column B = salary (data entry by users).

Naturally, the database changes over time. Employees are added and removed. Therefore, the data in column B needs to retain it's attachment to the name in column A. If an employee in Column A is removed, so too should the data in column B. However, if the sort order of employee changes in Power query (either new employee are added to the database or someone add a filter in the power query) then the data in column B should organize itself accordingly. Ex: If A1 ends up as A8 because 7 new employees are added then B1 should end up at B8.

The idea is to then take in columns A and B into a new power query for more modelling.

So I wonder how to go about this?

Comment: If you want to use powerquery, see https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/ regarding self referencing tables   Otherwise I'd actually suggest just creating a separate table and then merging on employee.  If the employee goes away, then the match doesnt take place for that row

Comment: That's not feasible because the list of employees comes from the database so I can't create a separate table because I don't know the employees beforehand.

Comment: But you can create a static table via copying the list of employees after the first import, which can then be maintained as often as required with your additional details. It could be automated such that any new names are added to this table via Power Query, else flagged via formulas looking at the main table. As horseyride suggested, you can then merge this table with your main table.